# Grpc remote server and Grpc local client

Tags: localhost, grpc, remote-server

I am trying to do a POC where i am trying to make my Site controller studio(client) on local system written in C# interact with the Server written in C++ hosted on remote desktop by using Grpc Protocol.
I tried following the below blog for the  C# client : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/basics?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Is it possible to communicate with the remote server from the client ?If yes,how should we give remote IP address?
A help would be good.

Comment: Do you know the IP address of the server? If yes, use `GrpcChannel.ForAddress`. Otherwise, you need to figure out how to expose the server first (but this is outside of gRPC scope).

Comment: i was able to communicate using IP address from within the remote desktop but when i try to connect from the local client ,it doesnt work.There is a firewall behind the server.Can anyone tell me how to bypass the firewall in the best way?

Comment: Then you can check more general questions on exposing a host behind the NAT/Firewall because this problem is not specific to gRPC. Another option is you can inverse server-client, so that the client will be on the host behind NAT and it will be connecting to the server (site controller studio in your case). Then you can use bidi-streaming call to communicate between client and server.

Comment: i am able to connect to the remote server from the local desktop powershell using command  test-netconnection myserver -port 1234
This means the remote server is getting connected from the local desktop but when i run local client using grpc protocol ,it doesnt.

I am trying  to run the client exe file on local desktop and try connecting it  to the remote server which is running ,the exe file vanishes with no error or anything.
I am not sure if its the Grpc error or something to do with my local desktop settings.

Comment: Did you write the client and server?  Do you have the code snippet that the client is using to attempt to connect to the c++ server on the external machine?

Comment: Right now,i am not working on  the C++ part.i am just trying to connect server on remote machine with client on the local machine in C# only.The connection is not happening .Do i have to change anything on the server side  in launchSettings.json ?What url  do we give in the applicationURL?

Answer (score 0):

The issue got resolved.I had not installed dotnet in my local machine.I installed it and it worked fine.
For connecting to the remote desktop,i used the code for https connection (i was facing invlaid certificate issue too here,it got resolved using HttpClientHandler):

var httpHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
// Return `true` to allow certificates that are untrusted/invalid
httpHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback =
HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator;

```
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        Console.WriteLine("hi,client connected");

        var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://{your ip address}",
            new GrpcChannelOptions { HttpHandler = httpHandler });
```

//You can insert the rest of the code for the client here..

Thanks a lot